# React Native: Serving URI from localhost not rendering the image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to display my uploaded image saved from to my backend folder. Its on different file so to retrieve I have to call it http://localhost:3333/userprofile/5/5.jpeg. But it does not work on my react native code, I tested it on both android and IOS

```
<Thumbnail
    small
    source={{
        uri: `http://localhost:3333/userprofile/${this.props.user.id}/${this.props.user.avatar}`
    }}
/>
```

it works when I open it on browser. It also work if I use different url like https://picsum.photos/200/300 how to deal with this?

Comment: You probably have CORS error

Comment: Are you sure `this.props.user.avatar` contains extension like `.jpeg`? If not you need to add it manually.

Comment: `source={{...}}` I have doubt on this json syntax

Comment: @LazarNikolic My cors config are open for all

Comment: @ravibagul91 if I outputed in text its exactly `http:/localhost:3333/userprofile/5/5.jpeg` and when I copy and paste on browser it works

Comment: @BGTabulationBGTabulate, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Comment: @ravibagul91 I tried but its not really working I don't know why, it works on base64

Comment: Is this the question that the Bot closed on React native issue tracker?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using android emulator you have to use `10.0.2.2` to access localhost on your PC. and if you're using a real device then you need to be on the same wifi network and have to use your PC's ip instead of `localhost`

Comment: Thank you, I replaced localhost with '10.0.2.2' and it worked

Comment: I've spent so much time on this and finally this answer saved me! Thanks a ton. It's really weird that the url works perfectly fine if we open it on the browser with localhost browser but not picking up from the component.

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images#network-images),

> Many of the images you will display in your app will not be available at compile time, or you will want to load some dynamically to keep the binary size down. Unlike with static resources, you will need to manually specify the dimensions of your image. It's highly recommended that you use https as well in order to satisfy App Transport Security requirements on iOS.

You need to provide dimensions for your image.

```
<Thumbnail
    small
    source={{
        uri: `http://localhost:3333/userprofile/${this.props.user.id}/${this.props.user.avatar}`
    }}
    style={{width: 400, height: 400}} //provide dimensions 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your IP Adress insted localhost
<Thumbnail
small
source={{
uri: `http://<Your IP Adress>:3333/userprofile/${this.props.user.id}/${this.props.user.avatar}`
}}
/>